# Posicionar pegada al top dentro de un div CSS

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente div con info y un span adentro como puedo hacer para que ese span este pegado al top del div para que se vea como en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
           <div class='chip green accent-2' style="font-size: 25px;">20
                <div style="float: right; font-size: 12px !important">
                     <span>
                          <i class="tiny material-icons">arrow_upward</i>10
                     </span>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes cambiar la propiedad `line-height` del div contenedor asi:

```css
div.chip {
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
           <div class='chip green accent-2' style="font-size: 25px;">20
                <div style="float: right; font-size: 12px !important">
                     <span>
                          <i class="tiny material-icons">arrow_upward</i>10
                     </span>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sirvio perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ponerle `position: relative` a tu contenedor `<div class='chip green accent-2' style="font-size: 25px;">` y `position: absolute` al contenedor `<div style="float: right; font-size: 12px !important">`. Para poder ajustarlo con `top` y `right`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
           <div class='chip green accent-2' style="font-size: 25px;position: relative; padding-right: 2rem;">20
                <div style="float: right; font-size: 12px !important; position: absolute; top: -5px; right: 5px">
                     <span>
                          <i class="tiny material-icons">arrow_upward</i>10
                     </span>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```